# Jenkins - persist plugin settings without using Descriptor

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I develop a simple Jenkins plugin. Here is the plugin class:

```
@Extension
public class Plugin extends hudson.Plugin {
    private static String URL;

    @Override
    public void configure(StaplerRequest req, JSONObject formData) throws IOException, ServletException, Descriptor.FormException {
        super.configure(req, formData);
        URL = formData.getString("url");
        save();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        super.start();
        load();
    }
}
```

And also I have the `config.groovy` that describes URL field at the `/configure` page:

```
package com.example.Plugin

f = namespace("lib/form")

f.section(title: "My settings section") {
    f.entry(title: "URL", field: "url") {
        f.textbox(value: my.URL) {
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I restart Jenkins my URL setting is lost. How can I persist it *without implementing a* `Descriptor` *class for my plugin?*

I tried to add `load()` method call to `configure()` and to `Plugin` constructor. Also I tried to override `getConfigXml()` method like this:

```
@Override
protected XmlFile getConfigXml() {
    return new XmlFile(Jenkins.XSTREAM, new File(Jenkins.getInstance().getRootDir(), getClass().getName()+".xml"));
}
```

But it didn't work out. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the way to solve this problem. Seems like Jenkins can't persist static class fields. My `Plugin` class now looks like this:

```
@Extension
public class Plugin extends hudson.Plugin {
    private String url;
    private static Plugin INSTANCE;

    @Override
    public void configure(StaplerRequest req, JSONObject formData) throws IOException, ServletException, Descriptor.FormException {
        super.configure(req, formData);
        url = formData.getString("url");
        save();
    }

    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        super.start();
        load();
        INSTANCE = Jenkins.getInstance().getPlugin(Plugin.class);
    }

    static String getUrl() {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Plugin instance is not defined yet");
        }
        return INSTANCE.url;
    }
}
```